# How to display ONE div at random

Tags: jquery, html

Below is code written by another user on here to show/hide a div with a random delay between 4- 8 seconds

```
<script>
    function showCity() {

      $('#city-middle').show();
      window.setTimeout( hideCity, 10 );
    }

    function hideCity() {
      $('#city-middle').fadeOut(200);
      window.setTimeout( showCity, 3000 + (Math.random() * 5000) );
    }

    hideCity();
</script>
```

So the DIV #city-middle (that appears & fades out) has a child div called #bolt-container that obviously appears & fades out with that div. Within this bolt-container are 4 child divs named bolt-1 to bolt-4. Each one of those divs has is positioned in different places.

```
<div id="city-middle">

    <div id="bolt-container">
        <div class="bolt-1">
        </div>
        <div class="bolt-2">
        </div>
        <div class="bolt-3">
        </div>
        <div class="bolt-4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need is for the #bolt-1 - #bolt-4 divs to appear at random ONE AT A TIME with no animation.

So far I've googled this and found only one jsfiddle which would possibly help - http://jsfiddle.net/tricinel/FgXDC/

I've tried implementing as below with no luck.

```
    function showCity() {
      $('#city-middle').show();
      window.setTimeout( hideCity, 10 );
    }

    function hideCity() {
      $('#city-middle').fadeOut(200);
      window.setTimeout( showCity, 3000 + (Math.random() * 5000) );
    }

    hideCity();


    var divs = $('#bolt-container').find('.div'),
    len = divs.length,
    randomDiv,
    speed = 1000;

var interval = setInterval(
                function() { 
                        randomDiv = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
                        divs.removeClass('show');
                        divs.eq(randomDiv).addClass('show');                         
                } , speed);
```

I know there is something wrong with how I have it laid out, but as a beginner, I have no idea where to even look! Could it be that I am not closing off the first jQuery thing correctly? Or not setting some form of function for the second one?

Comment: It should be: `var divs = $('#bolt-container').find('div'),`, not `.div`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To adapt the fiddle you posted, all you had to do is use:

```
var divs = $('#bolt-container').find('div'), //fetch all the divs
```

Notice that `var divs = $('#bolt-container').find('.div')` fetches all elements with the `div` **class(!)** that were descendant of the element with id `#bolt-container`. In your example, you do not want that, you want to fetch all the `<div>` below such element. That's what the adapted code above does.

And don't forget the CSS (will also be applied to all `<div>` below `#bolt-container`):

```
#bolt-container div {
    display:none;
}
```

[Check it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/FgXDC/65/).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I have tried the above changes here -http://deset.me/test_site/ but the bolt-1 to bolt-4 divs do not seem to be appearing at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Check this out: http://jsbin.com/icaqun/1/edit - You code is in the `<head>` of the page, meaning it is executed before all the `<div>` even exist. As you can see, I wrapped all your JavaScript code in `$(document).ready(function() {  /* your javaScript code */ });`. This means your code will be executed only when the page is done loading all HTML elements (and so the `<div>` will exist and work).

Comment: Excellent, that worked perfectly. So (document).ready basically means wait until page has loaded, then run the function. Learning something new every day! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah. Other alternative you could see around is `$(function() { /* your javaScript code */ });` ( http://jsbin.com/icaqun/2/edit ), which works the same way as `$(document).ready()`. Also you could have just put your `<script>` tag right before the end of the `<body>` tag, this way the code would be executed after the `<div>` and all existed in the page ( http://jsbin.com/icaqun/3/edit ).  For your case, either solution would work. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I would follow the already given suggestions (by @acdcjunior):

```
var divs = $('#bolt-container').find('div');
```

and:

```
#bolt-container div {
    display:none;
}
```

but I would also put all the code (*excluding the function definitions*) between:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Put your code here.
});
```

To make sure your document is loaded before working with its objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
var divs = $('#bolt-container').find('.div'),
```

should be:

```
var divs = $('#bolt-container').find('div'),
```

or simply:

```
var divs = $('#bolt-container div'),
```